# C# DateTimeOffset bad hour. Difference TimeSpan to DateTime and DateTime to TimeSpan

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

u_date = 1688066111

```
DateTime p_date = DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(u_date).DateTime;
```

Gives: 2023-06-29 19:15:11

```
long unixTime = ((DateTimeOffset)p_date).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

Gives: 1688058911   (2023-06-29 17:15:11)

How to fix that problem?

Comment: UTC+1 Warsaw, Zagrzeb,...

Comment: UTC+2 with daylight savings in effect.

Answer (score 3):

Doing it step by step will reveal what happens:

1. `DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(u_date)` will give you
   `2023-06-29 19:15:11 +00:00`, i.e. a date/time in UTC.
   [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.fromunixtimeseconds)
2. Getting the property `DateTime` will erase the time zone information
   (the resulting p_date has `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`).
   [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.datetime)
3. `((DateTimeOffset)p_date)` will interpret p_date as local time, i.e.
   in the *current timezone* which seems to be +02:00 in your case.
   [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.op_implicit)

You can fix this problem by avoiding the round-trip via `DateTime`, using only `DateTimeOffset`. Or - as Jon noted in his comment - by using the property `UtcDateTime` in step 2 (instead of `DateTime`) which will produce a a DateTime object with `DateTimeKind.Utc` (instead of `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`).

Comment: Or by using the `UtcDateTime` property instead of the `DateTime` property.